# Is one node mining enough in the private network to transfer and verify transfer?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

i have setup private blockchain. there are two node in that network. i started mining in only node1. i able transfer in node1 and node2.

Questions: 
Should i start mining in all node?
if start mining in node2, that mining helps to verify all transaction?
or 
without minging in node2,transaction will be verified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mine with one node and do transactions with the other if they are connected, which you can probably know through `admin.peers`
and if the second is synchronized you should see the result of it on both of them.

Comment: Just to add to this already good answer, the public Ethereum network probably has many nodes that are used only for transmitting transactions and do no mining themselves. In fact, very few nodes mine blocks frequently and new nodes, for all intents and purposes, haven't started mining (no one can tell until they submit a block solution).

Comment: Hi distic, then what is purpose of mining other all node? is one node enough for mining? can be other just node without mining?

Comment: It depends on how private is your network.
If it is entirely private (you are the only user), 
there is no point having several mining nodes.
However, if it is an internal blockchain in some organization,
say your firm, and if the internal coin has some value,
then it makes sense running several mining nodes to increase your probability to mine blocks.

Comment: Hi Distic, i have many doubt regarding ethereum. can you clerify me? shall we chat? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/25056/can-manage-node-in-my-ethereum-private-network