# Can manage node in my ethereum private network

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, private-blockchain

I have created ethereum private network. there are two node got connected with in this network. both are mining. I have created small contract for transaction. All transaction is happening through my application with my contract.

if i add other node:

1. Can i remove that node from the private network?(in case they do unwanted transaction)
2. Can i make other node has to use contract whenever they do normal transaction in ethereum console?
3. Can i restrict them to create contract?
4. Can i restrict them to do transactions except verifying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all those things are controlled by the Ethereum network protocol, not the smart contracts themselves.

In order to implement those features (able to kick a node off the network according to arbitrary rules, force usage of a given contract, restrict abilities to create transactions/contracts), you'd have to re-write the Ethereum client (effectively creating a fork of the client and network).

Comment: how can i re-write the Ethereum client

Comment: The Ethereum client is open-source. The core implementation is the [one written in Go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum); you'd copy that source code and modify it. That is no small undertaking and what you'd be creating is something completely different from Ethereum (a new cryptocurrency). Before doing that, you'd likely want to make sure the end goal you're aiming for cannot be done with smart contracts on top of Ethereum (much easier).